# If someone has been accessing my bank using a VPN will the bank have a record of the IP address of the device used

Tags: vpn

I have a business partner who claims has never had access to our LLC bank account. Will a subpoena to the bank be able to prove this is not true if I know his computer and phone details?

Comment: Ask your bank. They're the only people who can answer this question.

Answer (score 4):

If the person has used a VPN, the bank will only have a record of the IP of the VPN service. BUT, if they used an app on the computer or mobile, they *might* have a record of the specific device used to connect.

But frankly, this is not a question for random people to guess at, you should just ask your bank ...